# ¿Algún modo de animar un SVG que está inline en un CSS?

Tags: html5, css, svg

Tengo un SVG insertado completamente dentro de mi CSS, algo mas o menos así:

```
body { background-image: 
        url("data:image/svg+xml;<svg>MI IMAGEN</svg>}
```

Quisiera que se anime de un lado a otro del viewport. Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a lograr algo como [esto](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)? Te recomiendo buscar en Google: _css animate svg path_

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de un SVG simple inline en CSS?

Comment: @Mauricio en realidad lo que necesito no es animar un stroke sino mover un objeto SVG de un lado de la pantalla a otro. El problema es que por una cuestión de paths necesito tenerlo inline en el CSS

Comment: Podría ser usado en correos electrónicos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una vez que tienes el SVG como imagen de fondo, ya no importa que sea SVG, PNG, GIF o JPG: puedes animar sus propiedades como las de cualquier otro elemento/propiedad CSS usando animaciones y `@keyframes`.

En un comentario pones que lo que quieres es mover un objeto SVG de un lado al otro de la pantalla, eso lo puedes hacer con una animación sencilla que haga que el fondo vaya de derecha a izquierda y luego de vuelta sin parar. Algo como esto:

```css
body { background-image: 
  url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40'><rect fill='red' x='0' y='0' width='40' height='40'/></svg>");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0 0;
  animation: mueveFondo 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation: mueveFondo 10s infinite; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 

}

@keyframes mueveFondo {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 100% 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mueveFondo {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 100% 0; }
  100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

Lo que hace el código de arriba (todo CSS) es definir un SVG como fondo del `body` y luego con una animación se actualiza la posición del fondo con `background-position`.

Comment: Mil gracias @Alvaro es exactamente lo que buscaba hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar este plugin llamado fabric.js el cual tiene una opcion para animar svg http://fabricjs.com/svg-caching

Comment: me llegue a marear con los tigres

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, debes leer [answer], debes revisar tambièn lo referente a los enlaces.